# What do these votetypeids in the votetypes table mean?

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump

I have been using the data explorer to examine the stackoverflow data and I don't know what some of the votetypeids mean.

I am specifically interested in the following

1. Votetypeid 2: UpMod; is this equivalent to an upvote?
2. Votetypeid 3: DownMod; is this equivalent to a downvote?
3. Votetypeid 15: ModeratorReview; does this refer to a request for moderation or that the post has been reviewed by a moderator?
4. Votetypeid 16: ApproveEditSuggestion; does this refer to an edit has been approved or does it mean an edit is requested.

Comment: It's explained thoroughly in http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/174387

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Votetypeid 2: UpMod; is this equivalent to an upvote?

Yes.

> Votetypeid 3: DownMod; is this equivalent to a downvote?

Yes.

> Votetypeid 15: ModeratorReview; does this refer to a request for moderation or that the post has been reviewed by a moderator?

This refers to a moderator viewing the post after it's been flagged for moderator attention.

> Votetypeid 16: ApproveEditSuggestion; does this refer to an edit has been approved or does it mean an edit is requested.

This refers to someone voting to approve a suggested edit. It might take more than one vote to approve an edit. (Most sites require 2 or 3... and moderator votes are binding, so only one of those is necessary.)

Comment: What does `UpMod` stand for? Moderation? https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/1q8rik/why_do_people_sometimes_say_upmoddownmod_instead/ || http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=upmod