# What does "Mod" stand for in "UpMod"?

Tags: support, voting, data-explorer, terminology

I've gone through relevant posts such as ([Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/714660)) and ([What do these votetypeids in the votetypes table mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157532/714660)).

I am also aware that in terms of Voting, `2` means UpMod (AKA upvote)

I am just curious what does "Mod" stand for in "UpMod"?

Does that come from the word "moderator", "modification" or something else?

Comment: Mod is short for "Moderation": https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/341068/origin-of-upmod

Comment: "What's UpMod?" was my first thought.  Now I know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, your guess is right. Up- and downvoting is part of moderation, as reflected in the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges?tab=moderation) - those are *moderation* privileges and help separating the wheat from the chaff.

Note that SEDE is one of the few places where the term 'upmod' is used, presumably because it's stored that way in the Stack Exchange 'master' databases which populate SEDE. 'Upvote' is much more common: it has [over 6,000 hits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22upvote%22) compared to a meager [19 hits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22upmod%22) for 'upmod'. Except for a few hits which are more than a decade old, they're all about SEDE or the data dump (which has the same source as SEDE).

Comment: I think "upmod" is a Slashdot-ism, but that site has faded away from the prominent place it once held in Internet culture.